# Spring MVC Select tag haven't name veriable in html output

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

register.jspx

```
<form action="register" id="user" method="POST">
          <form:select path="factory">
                <form:options itemValue="id" itemLabel="name"  items="${factory}" />
          </form:select>
</form>
```

model

```
public class Factory {
    @Size(max = 255)
    private String name;
}
```

controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/html",value = "/register")
    public String UsersController.register(@Valid Users users,UserData userData,Factory factory,BindingResult bindingResult, Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            Logger.getGlobal().log(Level.WARNING, bindingResult.getAllErrors().get(0).toString());

            populateRegisterForm(uiModel, users);
            return "userses/register";
        }
        uiModel.asMap().clear();
        userData.setFactory(factory);
        userData.persist();
        users.setUserData(userData);
        users.persist();
        return "redirect:/userses/" + encodeUrlPathSegment(users.getId().toString(), httpServletRequest);
    }
```

and html output

```
<select>
<option value="1">aa</option>
<option value="2">bbbbbbbbbbbb</option>
</select>
```

Select tag haven't name veriable in html output. but i edited jspx file with path="factory"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enclose your `form:select` within a Spring `form:form`, and not just an ordinary form.

I'm pretty sure your JSP won't compile after you make that change - it looks like you may have other errors, but hard to tell without seeing the rest of your domain. Can you also add the controller handler/action that is called to produce the form view.